# Redux initialState append data into existing key

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutability

I tried lot of things but I can't achieved what want. I have an initialState in redux. It has 4 coin name as you see below. I'm trying to fill this keys with value from API. But at the end I have only 1 key with data.

```
import { SET_LIST, GET_LIST } from '../actions'

const initialState = {
    coins: {
        'BTC': {},
        'ETH': {},
        'LTC': {},
        'DOGE': {},
    },
    loading: false,
    error: null
}


const coinsReducers = (state = initialState, action) =>  {

    switch (action.type) {

        case SET_LIST: {

            const key = action.payload.key;
            const list = action.payload.list;

            let obj = Object.assign({}, state);

            obj.coins[key] = list;
            obj.loading = true;

            return obj;

        }
        default: return state;
    }
} 

export default coinsReducers
```

I iterate this initial state in  `app.js componentDidMount` hook and make api call with key. When I make api call with BTC key, I want to push the response into BTC key.

I hope someone help me.

EDIT: [Working Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-almeida-1znc1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Can you share a working example on CodeSandBox or any other platform where we can play around with the code and see the results?

Comment: One issue I see as of now is: `case GET_LIST: { return state.coins }`. The reducer function is not a getter function. Ideally, it should be `case GET_LIST: { return state }`

Comment: And, to add to that comment, you might not want to have `GET_LIST` action in the first place. Actions are something that would change the state. `GET_LIST` -- from the name of it -- aims to access a piece of state, _which_ a `reducer` is not meant for doing

Comment: @AnandUndavia this action type literally does nothing. The `state` will already be available to components via the `connect` function. Better to just not even dispatch an action from your `getList` action creator.

EDIT: just saw your other comment

Comment: @tobiasfried Actually yes, GET_LIST does nothing. I use `connect` to reach the data.

Comment: @AnandUndavia I working on to working example for share with you.

Comment: @YasinYörük with your example, every time you call the action creator that dispatches `GET_STATE`, you are actually overwriting your state object with a new state object that only has the `coins` property. Omit this action type, and don't dispatch it from your action creator.

Comment: Edit: added working example link.

Comment: The example seems to working just fine! All the keys seems to have proper values inside the state object.

Comment: @AnandUndavia If you press the refresh button you will see only one coin data in state.

Comment: @tobiasfried Delete GET_LIST action from reducer but nothing changed. Same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 case SET_LIST: {

        const {key, list} = action.payload;

        return { ...state, loading: true, coins: {...state.coins, [key]: list }};

    }
    case GET_LIST: 

// don't sure what you try to achieve here, anyhow what you are saying is that
// from now on all the state of the app it just state.coins

        return state.coins

    default: return state;
```

Comment: can you copy the console.log(state) after adding   { coins: { ...state.coins, [key]: list} } ?

Comment: Oh my friend, sorry, I missed the `...state.coins` part in your code. I realize that now and change my code with yours. It's working as I expected. Thank you very much. I'm appreciated :)

Comment: `GET_LIST` action is only trying. It was my first action in redux. Just I thouhgt to get data from redux.

Comment: @YasinYörük My pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

The reducer is used to update the state, not to get data from it.

The `GET_LIST` action returns `state.coins` which corrupts the state object, thus returning wrong values

Use store.getState() to get data from store